# pyqtgraph: how to make simple plot in vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plot, pyqtgraph

I am new to pyqtgraph but I cannot get it to work. I run the following code in VS code as a jupyter cell:

```
# %%
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = np.linspace(0,10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
img = np.sin(X)*np.sin(Y)
pg.image(img)
```

Then I get a frozen cell that is not responding. How do I get a simple plot in pyqtgraph?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `pg.exec()` at the end should do it. For more information for beginners I recommend looking into the example programs (run `pyqtgraph.examples.run()`). They can be quite complex but there are not a whole lot of other good resources as far as I'm aware.

Comment: That works! So simple